# In the Gallery from Intent.ACTION_PICK, can I override the longClick?

Tags: android, android-intent, image-gallery

In my app i let the user select one image from the media gallery. To do this i use the Intent.ACTION_PICK.
Like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK);
```

The app works mostly fine, the users can select an image and the uri correctly.

The matter is in the gallery. If the user does a tap on an image all goes well, image is selected and uri returned.
But if the user does a long click on an image, be it accident or on purpose, the phone vibrates a split sec, the image is focused, and then nothing happens.
I understand on the formal gallery app this brings up a menu, but in this case it does nothing, and it can be confusing to users, to think they tapped and see the app do nothing.

So the question is, can i do anything to change the behavior of the long click in that screen? Like override the `onLongClick` or set an `onLongClickListener` or something?

Thanks in advance, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do both, [**`onLongClick`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick(android.view.View)) is the method and [**`onLongClickListener`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) is the callback for that method.

Comment: But how can i access the method and callback in the gallery screen?

Comment: To achieve that, you might need to launch your own activity that shows gallery items and override it from there, I have tried looking online but nothing stands out to me.